# Como multiplicar todos os elementos de uma matriz por número em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

Preciso fazer uma função que dado uma matriz e um numero, retorna a matriz resultante da multiplicação de todos os elementos da matriz por esse número.

Tentei algo como isto:

```
def mult(matriz, n):
    resultado = []
    for linha in matriz:
        for elemento in linha:
            resultado = resultado + (elemento * n)
            return resultado
```

Mas está dando erro.

Comment: Você quer multiplicar cada elemento da matriz pelo número?

Comment: isso! ai retornar a matriz resultante da multiplicação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na linha 5 do código, quando você faz:

> ```
> resultado = resultado + (elemento * n)
> ```

Você está tentando utilizar o operador `+` entre dois operandos de tipos diferentes. O `resultado` (primeiro operando) é uma lista e `elemento * n` (segundo operando) é uma expressão que será avaliada para número.

Não faz muito sentido fazer esse tipo de coisa, tanto é que o Python lança um erro:

> ```
> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
> ```

Ou seja, você pode utilizar o `+` como operador de concatenação entre duas listas, mas não entre uma lista e um inteiro (como você tentou fazer).

---

Uma forma de se fazer esse tipo de operação é ir modificando a matriz passada a partir dos índices de cada *loop*. Para isso, pode-se utilizar o `enumerate`:

```
def mult(matrix, n):
    for lineIndex, line in enumerate(matrix):
        for elementIndex, element in enumerate(line):
            # Modificamos o elemento atual pela multiplicação de `n` e o próprio elemento:
            matrix[lineIndex][elementIndex] = element * n
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/2UIPtC).</sup>

Mas note que, com essa abordagem, estamos modificando a matriz original (tanto é que nem precisamos retornar nada da função `mult`. Uma outra opção seria criar uma nova lista e ir adicionando os elementos resultantes em cada iteração. Mais ou menos assim:

```
def mult(matrix, n):
    newMatrix = []

    for line in matrix:
        newLine = []  # Criamos uma nova linha

        for element in line:
            newLine.append(element * n)  # Inserimos o produto na nova linha

        newMatrix.append(newLine)  # Inserimos a nova linha na nova matriz

    return newMatrix
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/VTadeH).</sup>

E claro, dá para tornar mais conciso (e talvez menos entendível? :P) utilizando *list comprehensions*:

```
def mult(matrix, n):
    return [[element * n for element in line] for line in matrix]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/twHWCJ).</sup>